# Android browser don't download file from a HTTPS self-signed certified

Tags: android, spring, browser, download

We have a tomcat webapp self signed with a certified. When the user click in the help button then a pdf is downloaded, in pc browser it works but in android it stay downloading as  indifined time.

I use this code in the Spring controller:

```
URL url = servletContext.getResource("/manual/Manual.pdf");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Manual.pdf\"");
response.setContentType("application/octect-stream");
response.setContentLength(url.getFile().length());


try
{
        InputStream fis = url.openStream();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(fis, out);
        out.flush();

}catch(IOException ioe)
{
        logger.error(ioe);
}
```

We are using https and the port 9443.

I got this error in the logcat in android:

```
Application: android.process.media
Tag: DownloadManager
Text: Aborting request for download 23: 
      while trying to execute request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
      java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
      Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you check if your android device has the right set of time? I came across a SSL problem like that and fixed it by fixing my device clock.

Comment: Yes the time is correct I use the emulator and the time is configured the same. The server has the same time too.

Comment: Well in the error it says "Trust anchor for certification path not found.". You might wanna check your certification path, this might be a server problem, not client. Browsers nowadays are quite clever to fix any encoding problems and stuff like that. You might have a corrupted certificate url.

Comment: yes, it looks like that, but the website works good, only when I click to get the pdf the problem happens and in pc browser (tested with chrome) it works good

Comment: As i said, i've come across problems like that while i was having no problem on browsers, i had problems inside my client application. Most of the encoding problems are covered with common browsers these days. You can check if you have extra gaps or anything on your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the certificate was giving problems because was auto-generated. We used HTTP instead of HTTPS to download and this worked :D